# How to receive and store SMS in SIM rather than device?

Tags: sms, gsm

my question is how to make sure that SMS you are receiving is saved in SIM rather than device?

Comment: It depends on a phone model/software. Also notice, that SIM card has limited SMS entries, which can hold, while phone not (limit is memory)

Comment: Assuming that you have inserted sim for the first time, the first sms received will now go to sim or phone? How can i enforce to receive sms in SIM?

Comment: As I said previously, this is a phone software issue.
Nowadays (and for some years) phones tend to store SMS by default into phone, not at SIM card anymore.
SMS itself does have a flag, where to store SMS by default, set at SMS center by operator, but is always set to Automatic, which means, phone to choose.